# Java class.getResource() returns null

Tags: java, intellij-idea, resources, getresource

I am trying to use files in resource directory that was marked as "resource root" in IntelliJ, but the below code fails to find the file.

Could you tell me what was wrong? thanks.

[image: Project hierarchy]

```
public class ResourceTest {
    public void testResource() {
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("resources/table.1gram");
    System.out.println(url);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ResourceTest rt = new ResourceTest();
    rt.testResource();
}
```

}

Comment: "resources" vs. "resources2", "table.1gram" vs "table1.1gram".

Comment: @Marvin sorry there were typos, but it still doesn't work after fixing those typos.

Comment: try to change "resources/table.1gram" for "classpath:resources/table.1gram"

Comment: @RafałPieńkowski did you mean to replace "classpath" with actual class path? When I literally used "classpath:resources/table.1gram", it still returned null. :(

Comment: I suspect the path of the resource file. I'm not familiar with IntelliJ, but could you find out how the resource file and class file are placed in the target folder or OUT in your case may be?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure about IntelliJ's folder structure, but try to put your resource folder under src folder. And then try both approaches: with and without classpath

Comment: You could even try "/resources/table.1gram" to tell class loader to look from the root of jar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Files in the `resources` folder will be packaged to the root of the .jar file, meaning that during development, the `resources` folder itself is in the classpath, so you need `this.getClass().getResource("/table.1gram")`, or without the `/` since your class is in the unnamed package, aka also in the root of the .jar file.